# Cypress handling alerts automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, alert

The web app I am testing gives an alert. I wanted to use cypress to test if the alert is being shown and **click cancel** on the alert but cypress is automatically confirming the alert.

Here is the code:

```
cy.get('a').contains('Concepts').click();

cy.on('window:alert', (t) => {
//assertions
    expect(t).to.contains('You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?');
    return false;
})
```

I have returned false but still, on running the test, it says confirm without the assertion being handled and it goes to the new URL (which it should not). (see image below)

[image: Auto confirm by cypress]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are using `window:confirm` not `alert`.
Change it to `confirm` instead

```
cy.on('window:confirm', (t) => {
  //assertions
  expect(t).to.contains('You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?');
  return false;
})
```